# Scala Tuples, Manipulating Map Data

Tags: scala, list, recursion, maps, tuples

So I currently have a map set that has the data like so:

```scala
val mymap = Map ("Apple" -> List(1, 4 , 5, 7, 9, 8, 0), "Orange" -> List(5, 7, 2, 1, 8, 4, 3))
```

The data represent how many times each user has had one of these. I'd like to write a function that can display the key and then pull a value ie tail. I've not had much success and heard that tuple lists are hard to manipulate? Any help with this one?

```scala
def mapTail(list: String): Iterable[(String, List[Int])] = { val tailValue: Iterable[(String, List[Int])] = { mymap.groupBy(_._2).values.map(_.tail) } println(String) tailValue }
```

Is what I currently have.

Ps - Wasn't sure how to format the code as new to using Stack Overflow so if someone could kindly format it I'd be more than greatful.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you are looking for, but:

Transforming the map to the keys and the tail of original values:
mymap.map{ case(k,v) => (k, v.tail)}

Comment: Show what've you tried so far.

Comment: def mapTail(list: String): Iterable[(String, List[Int])] = {
  val tailValue: Iterable[(String, List[Int])] = {
    mymap.groupBy(_._2).values.map(_.tail)
  }
  println(String)
  tailValue
}

Comment: what about this?

def printKeysAndTail(map: Map[String, List[Int]]): Unit =
    mymap.foldLeft(Iterable.empty[(String, List[Int])])((o,n) => Iterable((n._1, n._2.tail)) ++ o).foreach(println)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do the following

```
mymap.map(x => x._2.map(y => (x._1, y))).foreach(println)
```

you should have output as

```
List((Apple,1), (Apple,4), (Apple,5), (Apple,7), (Apple,9), (Apple,8), (Apple,0))
List((Orange,5), (Orange,7), (Orange,2), (Orange,1), (Orange,8), (Orange,4), (Orange,3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but if you want the `tail` from each key:

```
mymap.map { case (key, value) => (key, value.tail) }

res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[Int]] = 
  Map(Apple -> List(4, 5, 7, 9, 8, 0), Orange -> List(7, 2, 1, 8, 4, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

or this:

```
def printKeysAndTail(map: Map[String, List[Int]]): Unit = mymap.foldLeft(Iterable.empty[(String, List[Int])])((o,n) => Iterable((n._1, n._2.tail)) ++ o).foreach(println)
```

the inner part is exactly the type you expect in your original code:

```
mymap.foldLeft(Iterable.empty[(String, List[Int])])((o,n) => Iterable((n._1, n._2.tail)) ++ o)
```